# Prove $4(a^2 + b^2 + c^2) + 9(abc)^2 \geq 21.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Could anyone advise me how to prove this inequality? Hints will suffice, thank you.

Let $a,b,c \in [0, \infty)$ such that $ab+bc+ ca =3.$ Prove $4(a^2 + b^2 + c^2) + 9(abc)^2 \geq 21.$

My attempt: By AM-GM inequality, $(abc)^{2}\leq 1$ and $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \geq 3(abc)^{\frac{2}{3}}.$

Comment: How did you get $(abc)^{2}\leq 1$? :)

Comment: $1=(a b+b c+c a)/3\geq ((a b)(b c)(c a))^{1/3}=(a b c)^{2/3}$.

Comment: @Kf-Sansoo, I do not know. But I will try to use it now. So the inequality is :$ x^3 + y^3 + z^3 + 3xyz \geq xy(x+y) + xz(x+z)+ yz(y+z) ? $

Comment: And what do $p, q, r$ denote in the inequality?

Answer (score 0):

If we assume the following condition (without loss of generality) $a\geq b \geq c$ then we have :
$$4(a^2+b^2+c^2)+9(abc)^2\geq 4(a^2+b^2+c^2)+9(c)^6$$

With your initial condition $ab+bc+ca=3$ the RHS of the inequality  can be rewritten as follows :
$$4((\frac{3-ab}{a+b})^2+(a+b)^2-2ab)+9(\frac{3-ab}{a+b})^6$$

Now we put $a+b=cst=x$ and remark that the inequality is minimal when $ab$ is maximal where the maximum value of $ab$ in term of $x$ is $\frac{x^2}{4}$

So we have to study this function :

$$f(x)=4((\frac{3-\frac{x^2}{4}}{x})^2+(x)^2-2\frac{x^2}{4})+9(\frac{3-\frac{x^2}{4}}{x})^6$$

But $max(a+b)=2$ so we have to study on the domain $]0;2]$ the function $f(x)$

It's clear that the function is decreasing on his domain and furthermore we have :

$$f(x)\geq f(2)\geq 21$$

So to conclude we have :

$$4(a^2+b^2+c^2)+9(abc)^2\geq 4(a^2+b^2+c^2)+9(c)^6\geq 21$$